# Recording sound in Electron.js

Tags: javascript, audio, electron, microphone, recording

I'm currently working on an experiential project building a sound recorder.
I will use an arduino with a button to start/stop recording, so that there are no interactions with the machine (a concealed Windows laptop) at all for the end user.

Looking for a way to record the sound on the machine from a microphone, ideally in Javascript.
The sound should be recorded locally (no dependency on Wifi connection) and each sound should be saved as a separate file.
Once the project is done/installed, I will have no access to the machine any more so the files need to be easily accessed by a non technical user (hence the arduino/laptop combo and not a raspberry pi for example).

My forte is JS so I was hoping to do it using Electron but I haven't found a way to do this just yet.
I have tried the obvious `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` which doesn't work on Electron for security reasons. There are a number of libraries out there but the ones I saw won't work at all, are outdated, and haven't been updated in years.
I also tried using p5.js, which despite being a bit convoluted worked quite well, but requires user input when saving the audio file, which is not an option given the installation will only have one button to start/stop recording an as interface.

Has anybody done this or is anyone able to put me in the right direction?

Comment: What is your question? What libraries did you try and why didn't they work for you?

Comment: I have edited the initial post with more information. Thanks

Comment: Have you managed to do it? If so, a solution would be appreciated...